# WPF Image.Source does nothing

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to set the **Image.Source** in the code behind to a relative path like this:

```
IMG_3.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("./Sprites/Layout/image1.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

If I use a non existing path, the program crashes.

But this path exists and works just like that as a **.Fill** in a Rectangle.
Whats wrong here ?

Comment: The program "crashes" because you don't catch the FileNotFoundException that is thrown by the BitmapImage constuctor. And what exactly do you mean with "Fill in a Rectangle"? You probably forgot to set the Image control's Stretch property according to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see nothing wrong here. Try using the full path instead. The `.Last()` is Linq so if you don't want to use this, just do the same thing with count - 1.

```
string exe = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName.Split('\\').Last();
IMG_3.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Substring(0, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Length - exe.Length) + "/Sprites/Layout/image1.png"));
```

Comment: What if the file still doesn't exist? Relative paths (same as absolute) work well as long as the file *is there*.

Comment: @Clemens But I want the possibility to edit these sprites just with the exe and the folder beside.

Comment: @JackGrey Ok, that wasn't clear from your question. You may then still use a Pack URI, for a content file in a folder structure that is relative to your application's assembly. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#content-file-pack-uris

Answer (score 1):

If the image files are located in a folder structure that is relative to the path of your application's executable assembly, you should load them by [Content File Pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#content-file-pack-uris) like this:

```
try
{
    IMG_3.Source = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Sprites/Layout/image1.png"));
}
catch
{
    IMG_3.Source = fallbackImage;
}
```